# how to create timein and timeout table in msql

Tags: php, mysql, date, time

I'm new to mysql and php. My problem is I want to `CREATE A TABLE FOR TIME-IN AND TIME-OUT`  wherein I can record a student's time-in and time-out.

But I have a table named `tblinfo` with `id as varchar`, `name, course` where the `id` will be the same as the `id` in the `timeinout` table(how to create this?).

How to make a relationship between this two table?

In creating the table for `timeinout`, i want my fields and datatype to be like this :

```
id varchar  
timein time  
timeout time  
date date
```

Please do help me to make some code for this.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm little bit confused as to how broad of an answer you are looking for

you can create the table just the way you said

`mysql_query("CREATE TABLE tblinfo (id varchar, timein time, timeout time, date date)");`

although I would advise doing the id as an int rather than a varchar.

As to how the time-in/time-out is obtained, for instance, when a student logs in or logs off or even comes to a page and then leaves it, really depends on what you're looking for.

The former method is easy, since, when the student logs in, you can start a`$_SESSION` variable and use `"INSERT INTO tblinfo VALUES(1, ".time().", 'NA', '".date("D M j G:i:s T Y")."')"`, and do the same for them logging out.

Having it know when the students have left the page is a bit more complicated but there are some tricks you can use to log a time-out for that.

Maybe you should elaborate a little more on what you are trying to do, programming-wise.

Comment: I'm sorry for my confusing question but since I'm new to mysql and php I don't know how to explain it. But thanks for trying to understand and answer it. Actually I'm making a Gatepass management system, but this part is just an option if ever the barcode reader fails to scan. So I have a textbox to input the IDnumber and clicking the submit button will record it to the timeinout table in mysql.

Comment: actually, I have already tried making that table but I don't know what's the main problem of it. Well here's my code to record the timein and timeout. 
if ('IDNumber' < 1){
   $sql_insert="INSERT INTO $tbl_name SET Date=CURRENT_DATE(), Timein=NOW(), IDNumber='$idnumber', FirstName='$fname', MiddleName='$mname', LastName='$lname'";
  
$result=mysql_query($sql_insert); 

}else{
   
   $sql_update="UPDATE $tbl_name SET Timeout=NOW() WHERE IDNumber='" . $_POST['IDNumber'] . "' ORDER BY Date DESC, Timein DESC LIMIT 1";
$result=mysql_query($sql_update); 
}

Comment: If IDNumber doesn't exist, it will insert a new record with time-in and update it with time-out. But if I add again another record with the same IDNumber, it didn't add but rather update again in time-out. pls help me with this.

Comment: and IDNumber should be in varchar since our ID# starts with a letter. ex. K20095875